# SSMS: Separating blocks of comments while collapsed

Tags: formatting, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Is there a way in SSMS editor to visually separate two comment blocks that are placed one right after another when the comments are collapsed?

Please look at the link below - remember that this code is just for demonstration purpose.

[image]

When this code is collapsed in the SSMS editor, I see all the commented code collapsed.

I want to be able to see each comment block as a separate collapsed region, as in below (this is an edited image) -

[image]

I did consider using a GO, but in my case this code is part of a stored procedure, and I have a BEGIN and END that encapsulates this part of code, so that will not work.

I thought of using BEGIN/END, but that will not work either because I only have comments and no code that goes inside.

The closest work-around I came up with is using a blank PRINT '' - but, I fee this is redundant, and even counter-productive when used inside a stored procedure that will always be called from the application and would never be run from SSMS except when debugging.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? Suggestions/direction of any free third-party plug-ins is also appreciated.

Comment: This is not a `TSQL` question; it's a SSMS question. When you're asking about specific software, it's helpful to indicate what version of that software you're using. There are functional differences between them. Please update the tags to indicate what version of SSMS you're asking about using. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for correcting Ken, I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 - updated now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do it without the comments collapsing into one region.

In SQL Server 2008 Management Studio (and probably most recent ones), you can use `{$REGION}` to at least give you a way to name or describe the collapsed region, which may help:

```
{$REGION "Comment One"}
-- This is comment one
{$ENDREGION}

SELECT dbo.

{$REGION "This is comment two"}
-- This is a separate comment
{$ENDREGION}

SELECT ...
```

[image: SSMS image capture]

But there has to be content between the two regions, or they still get merged into one.

The above also works while embedded inside `/*..*/` comments, too (which **is** valid T-SQL, for @scriptfromscratch), but it still merges the comments unless there is content between them:

```
/* {$REGION  "Test region 1"}
-- This is a test comment
{$ENDREGION}
*/

SELECT dbo.something

/* {$REGION "Test region 2"}
This is test comment 2
{$ENDREGION}
*/

SELECT dbo.
```

[image: Embedded regions]

[image: Embedded regions collapsed]

It looks to me like you'll need a third-party tool of some sort that provides this functionality, but I'm not aware of one that does this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you have link to documentation for this please? It looks interesting.

Comment: This isn't valid t-sql though. I would have thought any solution would have to maintain SQL compatability, which is why you see some 3rd party SSMS tools use comment hacks e.g. `--#region ... --#endregion`.

Comment: @PreetSangha: No, I'm afraid I don't. It's something I know from using Visual Studio, and tried in SSMS before posting the answer. I don't find a link in the SSMS SQL Editor docs for it, but it works (as my image capture shows).

Comment: @scriptfromscratch: The `{$REGION}` content is valid in SSMS 2008, and the purpose of the SQL content was to demonstrate the regions around them, not to be "valid t-sql". "Colapsing comments" isn't "valid t-sql" either.) Did you read the question asked? (Just checked, and SSMS **will** run the SQL statement in the window.)

Comment: @scriptfromscratch: See my edit, which **does** result in valid t-sql. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this - only worked when embedding in `/*..*/`, but still not an exact solution for my case since I don't have any content in between the comments - so the comments get merged.

Comment: @ChaithanyaM: It works both ways (as I demonstrated), but neither will allow separate comments (as I mentioned in my answer); both merge the comments unless there is content between them. Unless you can find a third party tool that allows this, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @KenWhite: thanks for the response - not trying to be rude, but for some reason it says Incorrect syntax near '{' when used without enclosing in `/*..*.` - it could just be my machine, though.  

Can anyone suggest/direct me to any such free/cheap third party tool which could achieve what I want? I appreciate that, thanks in advance!

Comment: @ChaithanyaM: I copied and pasted the code right out of SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 as is, and took the screen capture from the same version. You can see the syntax colors worked, so it didn't think there was an error. I don't know. ?? I doubt you'll find "free/cheap" tools that do this, though.  :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: Thanks again - I have SQL Prompt 4 installed, and was trying to find out if I can achieve this with it - but to no avail. I am curious, is there ANY tool at all that can do this (not just the free/cheap ones)?

Comment: @ChaithanyaM: Sorry; I've never seen one. I'm not sure I understand the need for it, either, but apparently you do. If you're lucky, someone else will have seen it too. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: I want to note that what I want is more of an aesthetic feature than a functional necessity; it is certainly something I can live without, if such thing does not exist. Thanks for all the support!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but as I don't see the simple solution I use, I thought I'd chime in.

I tend to use block comments mostly, and inline comments where there's only going to be one line or something short. If your closing block comment tag is followed by a semicolon, you can collapse any adjacent blocks independently, as shown below.

FYI this works in SSMS 2012, I can't vouch for any other version.

[image: Adjacent comment blocks followed by semicolons]

[image: Adjacent comment blocks collapsed]

Unfortunately this cannot work for adjacent inline comments. The OP would probably be better off using a block comment to enclose any adjacent/related comments into separate blocks instead.

Ken White is on the right track, however the `$REGION` stuff is unnecessary in my opinion. The following approach achieves the exact same effect, except much more cleanly.

[image: Comment block with simple title]

[image: Collapsed comment block with simple title]

Using `$REGION` to group commands would be equally clumsy, as flagrant use of `BEGIN END` blocks will do the same job. Just remember to indent properly to avoid confusion.

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks for the input @ubercam, I am doing something similar - my mine concern was with collapsed comment blocks not being visually separated, expanded comment blocks look fine though. I never had any luck with $REGION, SSMS does not recognize it at all. And, as with BEGIN END, it does not like when there is only commented code/text inside.